# Django saving data with form

Tags: django

I already saw many Stack overflow posts, but cannot find any problem on my code, but this code doesn't save any piece of data.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Post

class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'post_date']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import Http404

from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    latest_post_list = Post.objects.order_by('-post_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('form/index.html')
    context = {'latest_post_list':latest_post_list}
    return render(request, 'form/index.html', context)

def posts(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    return render(request, 'form/posts.html', {'post':post})

def posting(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    else:
        form = PostForm()

    return render(request, 'form/posting.html', {'form' : form})
```

posting.html

```
        <form action="/form/" method="post">    
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
        </form>
        <script src="" async defer></script>
```

I swear I saw many questions about it, but still I'm in trouble :/
I thought form.save in the views.py would make it work but no.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I am not sure if I understand what you mean by "but this code doesn't save any piece of data.". Please clarify the purpose of your code and also the bugs. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear.
I want to save this form and see it in my  Post model in admin site.
But after I send the post, it doesn't save any post, but definitely they move to url which I set on action.
I thought form.save() would save the form in database but it doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing action in your 'posting.html' and instead of creating `<input type='submit'>`try the below code for submit button.

```
<form method="post">    
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }}
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Thank you.
But why action was the problem of it?
I thought action is just link after I submit the form.

Comment: On submitting the form it will go to action page first without going to the function which captures the post and saves the content to db.

Comment: Thank you so much :) It helps a lot.

Comment: Happy to help.. could you please mark my answer correct for your question. Since it will be reference for others.